# Intersection of idempotent ideals

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ a commutative ring with identity and $I, J$ two idempotent ideals (i.e. $I^2 = I$ and $J^2 = J$).

The ideal $I \cap J$ will be idempotent if and only if $I \cap J = IJ$.  In any nice geometric ring this should be the case, because it holds whenever one of $I, J$ is finitely generated (or better, whenever one of $V(I)$ or $V(J)$ is closed under generalizations).

But I guess that in general idempotent ideals are not closed under intersection.  Could someone clarify the situation for me? Can someone produce me a ring with two idempotent ideals $I, J$ such that $I \cap J$ is not idempotent?

Answer (score 4):

I apologize if I have made a mistake here, but this idea looks correct and perhaps someone can justify the last point rigorously.

Let $ A = k[Z, X_1, X_2, \ldots] $ be a polynomial ring in countably many indeterminates. Let $ \mathfrak{q} $ be the ideal generated by the elements $ Z - X_1X_3, X_1 - X_3X_5, \ldots $ and $ Z - X_2X_4, X_2 - X_4X_6, \ldots $

Let $ R = A / \mathfrak{q} $. Consider the ideals $ I = (Z, X_1, X_3, \ldots) $ and $ J = (Z, X_2, X_4, \ldots) $ of $ R $. By the construction, $ I $ and $ J $ are idempotent ideals. To show that $ I \cap J $ is not idempotent, it suffices to show that $ Z \notin IJ $, as that would prove $ IJ \subsetneq I \cap J $.

Note that $ IJ $ is generated by the collection of elements $ X_oX_e $ where $ o, e $ are any odd, resp. even indices - the 'remaining generators' of $ IJ $ of the form $ ZX_k $ (and $ Z^2 $) are covered by the generators written down before. Assume that $ Z \in IJ $ in which case there is a relation $$ Z = \sum r_{oe} (X_oX_e) $$ for some finite collection of elements $ r_{oe} \in R $. But it is fairly clear that $ R $-linear combinations of elements $ X_oX_e $ do not have $ Z $ in the span.